# Xticks frequency of binned data

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question is quite straightforward and there is probably a really simple way to solve this which I couldn't find out.

I am plotting one pandas series which has the following format (note the binned data):

```
                       0
index                   
(0.0, 1.0]     -0.001563
(1.0, 2.0]     -0.014911
(2.0, 3.0]     -0.007187
(3.0, 4.0]     -0.003144
(4.0, 5.0]     -0.000145
(5.0, 6.0]      0.004209
(6.0, 7.0]      0.001705
(7.0, 8.0]     -0.000323
(8.0, 9.0]      0.000477
```

However, when I try to plot using pd.Series.plot (so the column 0 is the y and the index is x), I receive just a few points on the xaxis. I would like to set the tick for with more frequent bins. However, I haven't had any success as the index is now categorical and there is no tricks to set a numerical interval.

Any suggestion about how could this be solved?

**EDIT**
So, I have the following plot:

[image]

What I want, instead of showing the standard xticks set by the plot, I want to select which intervals are going to be shown. Lets say, instead of showing a frequency of every 50 intervals, I want to show a frequency of every 15 intervals

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your question? First the ticks are set for categorical axes as `0,1,2,...`. Then the index is used as label. A rotation helps to avoid overlapping labels.

The following example has 200 bins, and sets ticks every 15 positions. It also adds minor ticks (without label) every 3 positions.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.uniform(10,20,5000)})
cut = pd.cut(df['val'], bins=200).value_counts()
cut.plot(rot=90)
tickrange = range(0, len(cut), 15)
plt.xticks(tickrange, cut.index[tickrange])
plt.gca().set_xticks(range(0, len(cut), 3), minor=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

If your intervals are sorted, you could take the start (or the mid) of the interval as a label. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(0, 360, 2000),
                                          np.random.normal(92, 3, 200),
                                          np.random.normal(255, 3, 200)])})
cut = pd.cut(df['val'], bins=range(361)).value_counts().sort_index()
cut.plot(rot=0)
tickrange = range(0, len(cut), 20)
# t.left: interval start, t.right: interval end, t.mid: interval center
ticklabels = [t.left for t in cut.index[tickrange]]
plt.xticks(tickrange, ticklabels)
plt.gca().set_xticks(range(0, len(cut), 5), minor=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sample with simpler ticks]

Comment: Not really. I am using a huge chunk of bins, and I want to change the frequency in which they happen. In your case, you are plotting all the bins, I want to specify a few intervals that I want to appear on my xticks. If I plot all the bins the xtick labels won't be readable. When I plot for my case, it appears just a few xticks and I want to change the frequency and the interval that are showing on the plots. I will update the question and show a picture.